# How do I specify the file location for style.css in config.rb?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm using Sass and Compass and despite viewing some tutorials I can not specify the location where I want my style.css output to. This is my config.rb

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass" 
images_dir = "images" 
javascripts_dir = "js" 

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

output_style = :expanded # After dev :compressed
relative_assets = true
preferred_syntax = :scss
```

The style.css is being placed in the root instead of the css path.

My file structure is:

```
Root folder
 - css
 - images
 - js
 - sass
 - config.rb
```

Comment: That should not be possible, it should be placed in the specified css_dir.

Comment: Interesting point. I agree with it. So it's very likely some other kind of issue has occurred and I can't tell what it may be.